# Louville theorem and identity principle application on concrete examples

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have a two part question about Louville theorem, and identitiy principle:

**Loville theorem** states that if function $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $|f|$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is constant.

**Identity principle** states that if functions $f, g$ are holomorphic on area $D$ and if they match on set $A \subseteq D$ with limit in $D$ $\Rightarrow$ $f=g$ on $D$.

1. Does there exist function $f$ such that it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{ 0 \right\}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that the following condition is met $f(\frac{1}{n})=\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})$.

I can define a function $g(z) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2z})$ which exists on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \left\{0\right\}$ and does met mentioned condition. But is it also unique? I think that we can not use the the identitiy principle, because the interval where our functions are holomorphic $\left\{ \frac{1}{n}; n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} \backslash \left\{ 0 \right\}$ does not conatin the limit $0$. Also I cna define another function $h(z) = f(z) + \lambda\sin(\frac{\pi}{z} )$ which also satisfies all required conditions ($\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$). Is my reasoning corect?

2. Does there exist function $f$ such that it is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\left\{ 0 \right\}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that the following condition is met $n^{-5/2} < |f(\frac{1}{n})| < 3n^{-5/2}$.

I can define function $z^{5/2} < |g(z)| < 3z^{5/2}$ so $g(z)$ could be $2z^{5/2}$ and by identity principle $g(z) = f(\frac{1}{n})$. The function does therefore exist is unique and is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Is my reasonin here also correct?

I would like to get some feedback beacuse I find this chapter quite challenging and I do not know if I understand it properly yet. Thanks!

Comment: Couldd you explain in a little more detail what should I have done in part 2, because I am having hard time understanding what exactly you meant @Conrad

Comment: I was hasty as there are functions in part 2 actually since you can prescribe arbitrary values to $f(1/n)$ so in particular, you can find holomorphic functions on the punctured plane such that $f(1/n)=2(1/n)^{5/2}$ or any other value $a_n$ satisfying the required bounds; however $2z^{5/2}$ doesn't work as noted since it needs a branch cut; the proof requires standard results (Mittag Leffler and Weierstrass)